# Not able to write to excel at run time using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to write my test results/data to excel at runtime for which I have written the below code. I am not getting any error while compiling this code however the results are not getting written in this. Can someone help me out with the problem?

```
public void WritetoExcel(String filepath, String OrderID) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        System.out.println(filepath);
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        System.out.println("WorkBook Sucessfully");
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheetAt(0);
        System.out.println("Sheet Sucessfully");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator= ExcelWSheet.iterator();
        int RowNum =0;

        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row=rowIterator.next();
                RowNum++;
            }
        try
        {
            Row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=Row.iterator();
            Cell = Row.getCell(0);
            if (Cell==null)
                {
                    Cell=Row.createCell(0);
                    Cell.setCellValue(OrderID);                 
                }
            else 
                {
                    Cell.setCellValue(OrderID);
                }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e )
        {
            throw (e);  
        }

    }
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { throw (e); }` - seriously ?!?   `Row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);` how does this even compile?!?

Comment: By compilation I mean, it does not show any error. Between I am new to Java so avoid any syntax errors. Guidance would be appreciated

Comment: See if this link helps - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: Maybe the file is written correctly but to another location than you'd expect? Also: have you modified the code to post it here? As ammoQ indicated: Row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum); should not be able to compile.

Comment: @geoffreydv: It can compile if `Row` is a class member like `Row Row;`. Same with `Cell Cell;`. Unfortunately this is possible in `Java`. Variable names can be absolutely identically with class names. But surely one should not do this. Variable names should start lower case.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for pointing that out, I was mainly confused because I don't see the declaration of the variable in the provided code. It's probably declared somewhere else, maybe as a field declaration.

Comment: @geoffreydv- The file was writing correctly as you pointed out, however at a  different sheet. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to make this a comment, but it is too long.

There are a few comments I can make about your code.

First, it seems you are iterating through and counting rows that exist in the sheet. Then you are creating a new row at that index. Since a spreadsheet could have missing rows, this will only work for a very specific type of spreadsheet. That is, one which has no missing rows, and you always want to add the next row in the next empty spot. Instead of:

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator= ExcelWSheet.iterator();
int RowNum =0;

while (rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Row row=rowIterator.next();
        RowNum++;
    }
try
{
    Row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);
```

You can just as easily use:

```
int rowNum = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
Row row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(rowNum);
```

Then you write `orderId` in the first column of that row. Instead of:

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=Row.iterator();
Cell = Row.getCell(0);
if (Cell==null)
    {
        Cell = Row.createCell(0);
        Cell.setCellValue(OrderID);                 
    }
else 
    {
        Cell.setCellValue(OrderID);
    }
```

You could just use:

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(0, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
cell.setCellValue(OrderID);
```

In addition, for this you don't even need the iterators, but when you really need to iterate through the rows and cells of a spreadsheet it is better to use the for each syntax like this:

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        // do something with the cell
    }
}
```